# Tomcat 8 no reconoce Api REST

Tags: java, api, spring, rest, tomcat

Tengo una API Rest creada con Java 1.7, utilizando spring boot. Cuando inicio el servidor en eclipse (que utiliza un tomcat embebido) la aplicación funciona correctamente y cuando muestro localhost:8080/hola aparece el mensaje en JSON "Hola Mundo".

Ahora bien, tengo una máquina con Centos 7 y tomcat 8 instalado (es una instalación limpia, solamente la tengo para pruebas), en la cual hago el deploy del war generado. Desde App Manager puedo ver que el war está en ejecución.

Pero cuando intento acceder al war, o simplemente llamar a la API Rest me devuelve 404.

He probado con las direcciones:
localhost:8080/hola
localhost:8080/demo-demo/hola
localhost:8080/demo-demo.war/hola

¿Tengo que configurar algo más? ¿Qué puede estar fallando?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

**EDIT**

He revisado los logs. Se puede ver esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EDIT:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
      return builder.sources(Application.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: Revisa los logs del servidor (`[TOMCAT_HOME]/logs`)para ver qué está fallando. Puede ser un problema al inicializar la clase, por ejemplo.

Comment: He revisado los logs y he hecho un edit de la pregunta. En principio no veo nada raro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edito: Lo he conseguido solucionar gracias a lo que se comenta en este post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567434/spring-boot-application-gives-404-when-deployed-to-tomcat-but-works-with-embedde

Espero que sea de ayuda!!

Comment: Enhorabuena por encontrarlo. En un par de días podrás marcar tu respuesta como correcta, y así otros usuarios que tengan problemas similares verán más fácilmente que hay una solución.

Comment: Aunque sería mejor que (haciendo referencia a la original) añadieras el contenido de la respuesta aquí, por si en algún momento la respuesta enlazada se borra.